# asymptotic estimate for log-tan sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series

I am finding the following first order estimate.

> **Question.** As $y\rightarrow\infty$,
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log n}n\,\arctan\frac{y}n\,\,
> \sim\,\,\frac{\pi}4\log^2y.$$
>   Is it true?

Comment: By pretending arctan is constant for large y, you get an upper bound of the desired form.  By pretending log n is constant (OK, less than a fractional power) for large n, you should get a good lower bound. Is there an issue here I am missing?  Gerhard "Not Really Seeing The Issue" Paseman, 2017.01.07.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

Your sum has the same asymptotics as the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{\log x}{x}\arctan{\frac{y}x}dx$ by standard arguments (the integrated function is decreasing for $x>e$, say, and each specific summand is bounded, this is quite enough).

Next, we denote $x=y/z$ to get the integral $\int_0^{y}\frac{\log(y)-\log(z)}z\arctan z dz$. We have $\int_0^{y}\frac{1}z\arctan z dz\sim \frac{\pi}2\log y$ and $\int_0^{y}\frac{\log(z)}z\arctan z dz\sim \frac{\pi}4\log^2 y$, both by L'Hôpital's rule.